# Multiple image file upload only previewing first image in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've edited the original post as it had two separate problems and ultimately AKX in the comments helped me solve what the real problem was.

I'm trying to do an image preview for multiple images using appendChild as shown in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL), but when I go to submit the form and want to reset the page I'm noticing that using appendChild can be kind of an anti-pattern in React. I want to come up with a solution where I store an array of image tags that I could then just set to empty on submit to clear the page, as opposed to having to query select them all with document and remove.

With the code below I'm only rendering the first image out of a batch upload of multiple files. Single image uploads one after another work fine.

```
  const previewMainImages = (e) => {
    const files = Object.values(e.currentTarget.files)
    if (mainImageFiles.length + 1 > 10) {
      setErr(errMessage = 'Only 10 images can be uploaded here')
      return
    }
    
    function readAndPreview(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        var image = <img src={reader.result} alt={file.name}/>
        setMain(mainImageFiles = [...mainImageFiles, file])
        setMainImages(mainImages.concat(image))
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    if (files) {
      files.forEach((f, i) => {
        console.log(f)
        readAndPreview(f)
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't return anything from the `.map()`, which is what React cares about. Whatever you do in `reader.onloadend` is out of React's "reach", as it were. You will need to do the asynchronous stuff (reading the files) separately and stuff the results into state.

Comment: @AKX Okay I understand that approach, I just couldn't get it working a little while ago. If you have a minute would you mind just glancing at the Update I just appended to the post? With that approach I could get one file to preview out of a batch but not the others. I could also add one image at a time and have them all preview, but not a batch. I know it's an asynchronous issue I'm just struggling to see where.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have a bad time using the regular (non-callback) form of state setters with asynchronous code... Unfortunately I don't have the time to help you fix that right now, but you might want to consider storing an array or map of objects of the shape `{file: ..., preview: ...}` in state.

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea in general to store JSX elements in state. Just store the data you need to render those elements.

Comment: Ahh okay. Thanks I think I have an idea of what to try to next. Thanks for the JSX tip as well

Comment: @AKX Yea that was the first thought I had working on it now.

Comment: @AKX Got it! You helped lead me back to good old useRef, thanks for the assist, still learning. Also I was having to render img tags inside of div tags to assign keys so storing things as data objs solved that problem too, now I can just render the img tags with the key without the extra div. Thanks again I'm gonna update the post in a minute for clarity

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning javascript and React so I forgot about `useRef`. Also based on AKX's advice I also changed from storing image html tags to storing image data objects that I then map over to display the image tags in the form.

There seemed to be a problem where I was using two setState's and this was preventing the `.forEach` loop from iterating over all imgObjs.

So at the top of my file I define my useRef:

```
let mainImages = useRef([]);
```

I tried to remove both setStates within `reader.onloadend` but I found that the second setState for storing image files was actually needed to cause a re-render to ultimately display the images.

```
const previewMainImages = (e) => {
    const files = Object.values(e.currentTarget.files)
    if (mainImageFiles.length + 1 > 10) {
      setErr(errMessage = 'Only 10 images can be uploaded here')
      return
    }
    
    const readAndPreview = (file) => {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        var imgObj = {};
        imgObj.src = reader.result
        imgObj.alt = file.name
        mainImages.current.push(imgObj)
        setMain(mainImageFiles = [...mainImageFiles, file])
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    if (files) {
      files.forEach((f, i) => {
        readAndPreview(f)
      });
    } 
  }
```

And then in the relevant part of the html I'm simply doing this:

```
        <div
          className={'mainPreview'}
        >
          <h2>Main Images</h2>
          <p>{errMessage}</p>
          <input
            type='file'
            multiple
            name='image'
            accept='.png, .jpg, jpeg'
            onChange={e => previewMainImages(e)}
          />
          {mainImages.current.map((img, i) => {
            return <img key={i} src={img.src} alt={img.alt} />
          })}
        </div>
```

And then my reset inputs work like this:

```
  const resetInputs = () => {
    setMain(mainImageFiles = []);
    setBody(bodyImageFiles = []);
    mainImages.current = [];
    setDescription(description = '');
    setTag(tag = '');
    setTags(tags = []);
    setErr(errMessage = '');
  }
```

I'm still having a problem with the file input values not being reset but I'm going to leave that for another day.